# gdm3: unable to boot in 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, ubuntu-gnome, gdm

I restarted my computer which has (dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 and windows 10) because I was having some trouble installing and uninstalling virtual box. After the Ubuntu loading screen, the boot does not proceed and a [black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exgOz.jpg) is seen.
By typing the recommended command:

```
systemctl status gdm.service
```

I get the [following log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoqZr.jpg). 
I have tried restarting my computer and trying to run ubuntu in recovery mode but I am not able to access the recovery menu.
I can't understand most of the solutions online because I am new to Linux. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall gdm3 but for some reason apt-get install is not working. Is there any way I can fix this without having to use apt [(i get the following error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOR7d.jpg) or if I can boot from a live USB to fix this (don't know how that would work).

Comment: Run `echo "exec gnome-session" >> ~/.xinitrc`, then try launching the session manually with `startx`. Alternatively (or as well as this), you could install a different display manager until you can get gdm fixed, for example, `lxdm`.

Comment: I get the following output when I use startx `-bash: usr/bin/startx: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: no such file or directory`. Secondly i can't find a way to remove gdm3 and install another display manager without using apt and my apt is not working as well.

Comment: Looks like `startx` is trying to call on the legacy `sh` instead of `bash`. I'd advise making `sh` a symlink to `bash` by running `sudo ln -sfv /bin/bash /bin/sh`. Then try again.